# Code knight's tour using backtracking is not showing any output

Tags: c++, c, graph, knights-tour

This code is not giving any output. It should output a matrix of 8X8 size.

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 8
using namespace std;
```

This function prints the matrix:

```
void print(int arr[][N]){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

This function checks limits of x and y and whether knight already visited that place or not.

```
bool safe(int x, int y, int arr[][N]){
    if(x>=0 && y>=0 && x<N && y<N && arr[x][y] == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function do most of the things:

```
bool solveKT(int x, int y, int movei, int arr[][N], int xmove[], int ymove[] ){
    if(movei == (N*N)+1){
        return true;
    }

    for(int k=0 ; k<8 ; k++){
        int nextx = x + xmove[k];
        int nexty = y + ymove[k];

        if(safe(nextx, nexty, arr) == true){
            arr[nextx][nexty] = movei;
            if(solveKT(nextx, nexty, movei+1, arr, xmove, ymove) == true){
                return true;
            }
            arr[nextx][nexty] = 0; // backtrack
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is just a driver function:

```
int main(){

    int arr[N][N]={0};
    int xmove[] = {1, 1,2, 2,-1,-1,-2,-2};
    int ymove[] = {2,-2,1,-1, 2,-2, 1,-1};
    arr[0][0] = 1;
    int movei = 2;
    bool a = solveKT(0, 0, movei, arr, xmove, ymove);
    if(a == true){
        print(arr);
    }
    else
        cout<<"no solution";

}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag and remove the language from the title, and more importantly write a more descriptive title

Comment: Sure, the debugger can. Learn to compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) - e.g. to run your program step by step.

Comment: How about adding some tracing output showing you what the program does and what it does not? Come on, basic debugging isn't that hard...

Comment: **Wait**... are you really trying to **brute-force** a solution for the Knight's Tour? [4x10^51 possible move sequences](http://www.josiahland.com/archives/781)? When do you expect the solution to print? Within your life span?

Comment: yes know its not hard to debug. but the thing is i am using recursion and 8X8 so adding some tracing output is becoming difficult and i am not that experienced in programming.

Comment: its not brute-force.. using backtracking. this program will not consider all the configuration. here is the link of what i am trying to do.  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-1-the-knights-tour-problem/

Comment: How is going through all possible moves until you find a valid sequence *not* brute-forcing? Your `xmove` array has the first move not going to the right at index `[4]`...

Comment: Every time I see c and c++ tags in the same question i swear i will not look at this crap ever again. Yet, I'm still reading this...

Comment: @zubergu: To give the OP credit, in this case the issue actually *is* topical for both C and C++. Aside from him using `cout` instead of `printf()`, users from both tags would be able to help him out -- and that's the purpose of those tags, isn't it?

Comment: @DevSolar: Pruning as soon as a path self-intersects and backtracking is a LOT more efficient than brute force enumeration of all possible sequences of 64 knight moves.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Still unoptimized as heck, and his problem is simply that the program takes ages to complete.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the solution is unoptimized and time of excution changes with reordering of xmove and ymove. It gives best result when xmove and ymove has 2 and 1 respectively as their first value... Thanks everyone...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the following code:

```
if(movei == (N*N)+1){
    return true;
}
```

...with a hardcoded value...

```
if(movei == 62){
    return true;
}
```

...gave me a good result after 0.1 seconds. (A field with only three "zeroes" remaining.) So your overall algorithm works.

Hint for better looks of the output:

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << setw(3) << arr[i][j];
```

Bumping the `62` to `63` increased the runtime to 2.5 seconds, with only two zeroes on the field. Still waiting for the `64` run to finish.

**Edit:** Half an hour later, the `64` run still didn't finish. Point made.

Your problem is not the program, your problem is the algorithm. It has to go through trillions of moves to get a result. The complexity is killing you, as I guessed.